# Cordova Setup : Getting error message "Please run android emulator" in net-beans

Tags: android, cordova, netbeans, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

> I am facing issue while setting up Cordova in NetBeans.
>      Following options are already set up in my system :

```
Java SDK,
Cordova,
Andriod NetBeans plugin
Andriod studio SDK
```

After creating sample Cordova project in Netbeans, I am not able to run in Emulator.
Below is error message I am getting.

[Error Message: Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLogB.png)

Or Suggest any other IDE for Cordova.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Andriod studio > Tools > ADV manager > select and add virtual device. In default doen't have any device.